# How to normalize screen size

Tags: algorithm

I have a lot of many mobile screen standard.Example :

```
240x320
320x480
480x800
........
```

But in log i received many screen size (This screen size was detected by javascript then send to the webserver, when device access my website) :example  241x322, 239x320, 481x799 ... This size was wrong any pixel at height , weight  or both of height and weight
What is the best of algorithm, or library to normalize screen size (know size 241x322 is 240x320).

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by "normalize?"

Comment: how about math.round()? And I really don't get why the javascript got 241x322 instead of 240x320..

Comment: this size is browser height, and weight. In a few cases this size was wrong any pixel.

Answer (score 0):

You could run a simple algorithm that searches for the closest match, and change to that.

Run a loop looking for the distance (absolute value) from all heights / weights, and get the min one.

If you do them in ascending/descending order, you can break once you see the changes grow to improve efficiency.

You could also make sure the aspect radio is right as a measure of extra safety.